# Determining the weights of known parameters in a formula

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, order-statistics

I have a formula of the following form:

$a_1*w + a_2*x + a_3*y + a_4*z$

In the above formula, the $a_i$s can be thought of as weights to the corresponding parameters. The values of the parameters $w, x, y,$ and $ z$ are ***known*** whereas the $a_i$s are ***unknown***.

The above formula **aims to assign 'values'** to certain objects *after the $a_i$s become known*. After making an initial guess about the $a_i$s, I am able to assign the values(There are about 50 such objects whose values have to be assigned with the above formula) ***and rank the objects in a decreasing order*** based on the values obtained and **compare the obtained ranking of the objects *with the ranking they should have obtained*** (which is determined by other means) through various statistical parameters such as *covariance, corelation* etc.

---

**PROBLEM**:

Now, I want to determine which $a_i$ (or for that matter, which *term*) in the above equation contributed the most to the ***ranking order obtained from the formula*** (i.e., which $a_i$ was the most significant in getting the obtained ranking).
**Is there any statistical way to determine this?**

Comment: if any mathematical method(s) exist(s) for the above problem instead of statistical, _you are also welcome to point that(those) method(s) too_.

Comment: It will depend on what you mean by "most significant".  You also have other issues: e.g. multiplying all the $a_i$ by a positive constant will give the same ranking; if the $w,x,y,z$ are not comparable in some sense (similar units or similar dispersion) then comparisons of the $a_i$ may not be meaningful.

Comment: @Henry Hello, by "most significant" I mean that the term that accounts "the most" for the ranking. (The weights are the same for all objects but the values of $x, y, z, w$ are different for different objects). Assuming that $x, y, z, w$ are comparable, what can be the possible approach to this?